# Maintaining a log file for a Session for an Application developed in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing an Application in Qt & it is near completion now. Until now I have heavily relied on `QDebug()` for printing me the errors while *Debugging*. But now I want to maintain a **Log file** which will contain all the details of user interaction & the value of all the variables that I want to monitor at various state's. This is so that suppose my user experiences a crash then I will ask him to just submit the Log file to me so that I can understand the problem. Currently I can think of a mechanism by which I can maintain a reference of the Log file in all my classes (there are many!) & just append the `QString` in the end. But I think that might not be thread safe, plus it will be quite tedious to maintain the File. I wanted to know if there is already any inbuilt feature in Qt by which I can just give it my string's & it will maintain a single file automatically?
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QDebug itself can write to a log file.

> QDebug is used whenever the developer needs to write out debugging or tracing information to a device, file, string or console.

On startup, set the qt message handler with [qInstallMsgHandler()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler).

Within the message handler, to write to a file you can use a QDebug object created with the constructor below. Pass it a QFile.

> QDebug::QDebug ( QIODevice * device )

Comment: usually I do something like this:
QDebug() <<"My text here.";
I dont create any objects just print it like that directly.
So do you mean that I should create objects with that constructor & call some func() which prints the QString. ?

Comment: You can continue to use qdebug()<<"My text here" throughout your code. On startup, set the qt message handler with this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler. Within the message handler, you can use the constructor above to write to a file.

Comment: You're welcome. Edited the answer to include the part about qInstallMsgHandler().